# Java reflection getDeclaredMethod throws NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection

I have a private method `getListSonarMetricsFromRegistry` declared in the Class `SonarRestApiServiceImpl` that I want to call, with Java reflection, but I get the exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cma.kpibatch.rest.impl.SonarRestApiServiceImpl.getListSonarMetricsFromRegistry(java.util.HashMap)
>       
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
>       
> at com.test.service.rest.SonarRestApiServiceImplTest.testGetListSonarMetricsFromRegistry(SonarRestApiServiceImplTest.java:81)

---

I tried to use Java reflection, like below :

```
    @Test
    public void initTest() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Map<Long, KpiMetric> tmp = new HashMap<>();
        Method method = sonarRestApi.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getListSonarMetricsFromRegistry", tmp.getClass());
        method.setAccessible(true);
        List<String> list = (List<String>) method.invoke(sonarRestApi, registry.getKpiMetricMap());
    }
```

Here is the `getListSonarMetricsFromRegistry` method declaration:

```
//This method works correctly, it returns a List of String without error
private List<String> getListSonarMetricsFromRegistry(Map<Long, KpiMetric> map) {
    return //something
}
```

---

When I look at the Exception, the trace print my Class with the right package, right name, right method name and right parameters:

> com.test.rest.impl.SonarRestApiServiceImpl.getListSonarMetricsFromRegistry(java.util.HashMap)
>   But it say that this method does not exist, which is strange.

The similar questions provided by Stackoverflow did help, but I still have the same Exception.

Comment: `HashMap` is not the same as `Map` - one is the `interface` the other the implementation. Your call to `getDeclaredMethod` uses `tmp.getClass` which will return `HasMap.class` and your method takes a `Map`. You need to call with `Map.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you give a `HashMap` class instance as an argument to `getDeclaredMethod` while the method actually accepts `Map` class instance. Remember, that all generic arguments are stripped out on compilation, so a `Map<Whatever,WhateverElse>` simply becomes a `Map` when doing reflection at runtime. So try:

```java
 Method method = sonarRestApi.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getListSonarMetricsFromRegistry", Map.class);
```

On a related note, basing tests on reflectively calling private API is probably not a good way to keep tests maintainable in the long run. I'm not sure why you would need to do this trickery, but if you can,  try to find a way that works with public API.

Comment: Indeed that solve the issue, you are also right about what I am doing, being a trick, I'll see if I can find another way of doing, thanks for the help